# Java Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details

Tags: java, generics

I have a ton of code and I get the message

```
Note: GenericSet.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

I don't really want to post all of the code but if you guys could tell me a way to compile and find the error that would be great. I know it has to deal with Generics I just don't know how to find where in the code the problem occurs.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class GenericSet<T> implements ExtendedSet<T> {

    private ArrayList<T> myList;

    public GenericSet() {
            myList = new ArrayList<T>(50);
    }

    public ArrayList<T> getList() {
        return this.myList;

    }


    public void addThis(T item) {
        this.myList.add(item);
    }

    public ExtendedSet<T> intersection(ExtendedSet<T> set) {
        ArrayList<T> compareThis = ((GenericSet<T>)set).getList();
        GenericSet<T> finalVal = new GenericSet();
        for (T item : compareThis) {
            if (this.myList.contains(item)) {
                finalVal.addThis(item);
            }
        }
        return finalVal;
    }


    public ExtendedSet<T> difference(ExtendedSet<T> set) {
        ArrayList<T> compareThis = ((GenericSet<T>)set).getList();
        GenericSet<T> finalVal = new GenericSet();
        for (T item : compareThis) {
            if (!(this.myList.contains(item))) {
                finalVal.addThis(item);
            }
        }
        return finalVal;
    }

    public ExtendedSet<T> union(ExtendedSet<T> set) {
        ArrayList<T> base = this.getList();
        ArrayList<T> compareThis = ((GenericSet<T>)set).getList();
        GenericSet<T> finalVal = new GenericSet();
        for (T item : compareThis) {
            if (!(this.myList.contains(item))) {
                finalVal.addThis(item);
            }
        }
        for (T item: base) {
            finalVal.addThis(item);
        }
        return finalVal;
    }

    public ExtendedSet<T> symmetricDifference(ExtendedSet<T> set) {
        GenericSet<T> diffSet = new GenericSet();
        ArrayList<T> compareThis = ((GenericSet<T>)set).getList();
        ArrayList<T> base = this.getList();
        for (T item : compareThis) {
            if (!(this.myList.contains(item))) {
                diffSet.addThis(item);
            }
        }
        for (T item : base ) {
            if (!(compareThis.contains(item))) {
                diffSet.addThis(item);
            }
        }
        return diffSet;
    }

    public ExtendedSet<ExtendedSet<T>> powerSet() {
        GenericSet<ExtendedSet<T>> powerSet = new GenericSet();
        for (int i = 0; i<(this.myList.size()); i++) {
            GenericSet<T> newSet = new GenericSet();
            for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                newSet.addThis(this.myList.get(k));
            }
        powerSet.addThis(newSet);
        }
    return powerSet;
    }

    public ExtendedSet<Tuple<T>> product(ExtendedSet<T> set) {
        GenericSet<Tuple<T>> product  = new GenericSet();
        Object aList = this.myList.clone();
        ArrayList<T> bList = ((GenericSet<T>)set).getList();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.myList.size(); i++) {
            GenericTuple addMe = new GenericTuple(((ArrayList<T>)aList).get(i), bList.get(i));
            product.addThis(addMe);
        }
        return product;
    }

    public <E> ExtendedSet<E> map(LMap<T, E> map) {
        GenericSet<E> finalVal = new GenericSet();
        for (T item: this.myList) {
            E ans = map.map(item);
            finalVal.addThis(ans);
        }
        return finalVal;
    }

    public T reduce(LReduce<T> reduce) {
        ArrayList<T> run = this.getList();
        T end = run.get(0);
        for (T item: this.myList) {
            if (item != run.get(0)) {
                end = reduce.reduce(end, item);
            }
        }
        return end;
    }

    public ExtendedSet<T> filter(LFilter<T> filter) {
        GenericSet<T> finalVal = new GenericSet();
        for (T item: this.myList) {
            if (filter.filter(item)) {
                finalVal.addThis(item);
            }
        }
        return finalVal;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!(o instanceof GenericSet)) {
            return false;
        }

        GenericSet<T> testMe = (GenericSet<T>) o;
        boolean ans = true;
        ArrayList<T> test = this.getList();
        ArrayList<T> compare = testMe.getList();

        for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
            if (test.get(i) != compare.get(i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void clear(){
        this.myList.clear();
    }

    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        boolean ans = this.myList.removeAll(c);
        return ans;
    }

    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        boolean ans = this.myList.retainAll(c);
        return ans;
    }

    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        boolean ans = this.myList.addAll(c);
        return ans;
    }

    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        boolean ans = this.myList.containsAll(c);
        return ans;
    }

    public int size() {
        int ans = this.myList.size();
        return ans;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        boolean ans = this.myList.isEmpty();
        return ans;
    }

    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        boolean ans = this.myList.contains(o);
        return ans;
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        Iterator<T> ans = this.myList.iterator();
        return ans;
    }

    public Object[] toArray() {
        Object[] ans = this.myList.toArray();
        return ans;
    }

    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        T[] ans = this.myList.toArray(a);
        return ans;
    }

    public boolean add(T e) {
        boolean ans = this.myList.add(e);
        return ans;
    }

    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        boolean ans = this.myList.remove(o);
        return ans;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int ans = this.myList.hashCode();
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the following code:

```
GenericSet<ExtendedSet<T>> powerSet = new GenericSet();
```

With

```
GenericSet<ExtendedSet<T>> powerSet = new GenericSet<ExtendedSet<T>>();
```

In all your declarations. If you use an IDE like eclipse the code with warnings will be underlined in yellow making it simple to find issues.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that in some points of your code your are forgetting to do the generic declaration as in:
`GenericSet<T> newSet = new GenericSet();`
It's supposed to be:
`GenericSet<T> newSet = new GenericSet<T>();` or in Java7 or above:
`GenericSet<T> newSet = new GenericSet<>();`

Fix this declarations and the warning goes away.